# Symfony2 form events and form collection PRE_SET

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a question regarding a Symfony 2 application i'm working on.

I'm having the following model :

```
class Product:
- entity Category

class Attribute:
- string name
- string type (can be "free text" or "entity")

class AttributeValue
- entity attribute
- string value

class Category:
- string name
- collection attributes (manyToOne attribute)

class ProductAttribute
- entity product
- entity attribute
- string value (could be an ID for AttributeValue or text)
```

Which means :

- A Category can have zero or many attributes
- A Product depends of a Category
- When adding a new Product to the database, custom fields are displayed following the category choices and its attributes (example : if we are in the category Shoes we ask for the attribute Size which is a field made of every AttributeValue linked).

I've read the tutorial on Symfony2 about the FormEvents PRE_SET_DATA and POST_DATA but it's quite complicated and i'd appreciate some help to clear this up.
By the way, the tutorial in Symfony 2 is about editing an entity type field. As i was planning my code, i figured i should be using a collection type but i don't really see how i'm supposed to set data inside a collection field type...

If anyone comes by and could give a hand, it would be very kind :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to submit the product form to the database. After that you can build a form for choosing categories.